# Empty WebSite without code-behind imitate MVC

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I create a new WebSite: File -> New -> WebSite (empty WebSite without helping files and folders).
And I want to create the registration form (I use in Bootstrap and aspx files without code behind of C#).
When I click to the "Register" button I want that my all data what putted in text boxes passed to the C# file or to the SQL Server.How can I do this ?

I'm adding a some script and source file also

I'm very Thank you for help!

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var Page = (function () {

                var $navArrows = $('#nav-arrows'),
        slitslider = $('#slider').slitslider({
            autoplay: true
        }),

      


        init = function () {
            initEvents();

            $("#register").validate({           
                rules: {
                    email: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    },
                    username: {
                        minlength: 3, required: true
                        
                    },
                    password: {minlength: 3, required: true},
                     password_confirm: {minlength: 3, required: true, equalTo: "#password"}


                },
                  messages: {
        username:   {required: "You need to enter a Username."},
        email:      {required: "You need to enter an Email Address."},
        pass1:      {required: "You need to enter a Password."},
        pass2:      {required: "You need to enter your password again.", equalTo: "Your passwords don't match."},
        country:    {required: "You need to tell us where you live."},
        tandc:      {required: "You need to read and agree to the Terms and Conditions to use CGE."}
        },
            })

        },
        initEvents = function () {
            $navArrows.children(':last').on('click', function () {
                slitslider.next();
                return false;
            });

            $navArrows.children(':first').on('click', function () {
                slitslider.previous();
                return false;
            });
        };

                return { init: init };

            })();

            Page.init();
        });
    </script>
```

```html
<fieldset class="registration-form">
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <!-- Username -->
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" class="input-xlarge">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <!-- E-mail -->
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" class="input-xlarge">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <!-- Password-->
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="input-xlarge">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <!-- Password -->
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="password" id="password_confirm" name="password_confirm" placeholder="Password (Confirm)"
                                class="input-xlarge">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                     <div class="control-group">
                        <!-- Password -->
                        <div class="controls" style="line-height:20px;">
                        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="newsletter"/>&nbsp;<span style="position:relative;top:3px;font-weight:bold;font-size:14px;">Newsletter</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <!-- Button -->
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="submit" id="send" class="btn btn-success btn-large btn-block" value="Register">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
```

Comment: So ... you want the data to go to C#, but without using any C#? I'm not sure what you're askingfor here.

Comment: You should create an MVC web application project.

Comment: Yeah.. of course I need that data what putted come to C# file or if you understand how can I send the data from text boxes to SQL. But there is one problem the project isn't MVC but is WebSite. How can I solve the problem? You can help me?